# How to force Facebook app to ask for permissions?

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am using the following code to generate a Facebook login link:

```
<?php
try {
 include_once 'facebook_sdk_libs/facebook.php';
} catch(Exception $o){
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($o);
 echo '</pre>';
}
// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => APPID,
  'secret' => APPSECRET,
  'cookie' => true,
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();

function d($d){
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($d);
 echo '</pre>';
}

$fbme = null;
// Session based graph API call.
if ($session) {
 try {
  $uid = $facebook->getUser();
  $fbme = $facebook->api('/me');
 } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  //  d($e);   
 }
}

if($fbme){
 $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else { 
 $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
  array('scope' =>  'publish_stream')
 );
}
```

It shows a screen where Facebook shows "Go to App" AND "Cancel". When I click "Go to App", it returns back to my page, but does not post on Facebook wall as I want.

What do I need to change in this code to make Facebook ask and get the permission to "Post on Wall"?

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your participation, i have take note of your clue about access_token and found this code working , I just replace getlogin code with this one

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'canvas' => 1,
    'fbconnect' => 0,
    'req_perms' => 'email,publish_stream,status_update,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history'));
```

it first authenticate my app then on next step it ask for post wall permissions. so it does this in single step,

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The operation you are doing will only make the user authenticate your app and for facebook will return to you. This won't cause Facebook to post to the user's wall. If you wish to do that, there are two options:

- On return from the Facebook's authentication, you can have a button on the page for "Post to wall" and the use the JS SDK's [FB.ui 'feed' dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) to request user to post to wall. Of course, this won't necessarily means users will post to wall - they may choose not to.
- On return make a server side call to Graph API with the returned access_token to post a [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#links), [post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts) or [status](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#statuses) on the user's wall. Read [Graph API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/).